# How to run only part of my code in a loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to optimize my code. For the moment I have a while loop in which several sensors are read out. But in the beginning of my code I first check what sensors that needs to be read out and I simply add an if function before every part of code. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
sensor1_actif=1
sensor2_actif=0

while True:
    if(sensor1_actif==1):
        x=sensor1read()
    
    if(sensor2_actif==1):
        y=sensor2read()

    ...
```

Comment: Maybe create a list of active sensors, and have a `for sensor in active_sensors:` loop inside your `while` loop?

Comment: You can use `True` and `False` instead of `1` and `0`; it's easier to understand. Also, using `if sensor1_actif:` is equivalent to using `if sensor1_actif == True:`.

Comment: What are `sensor1read()` and `sensor2read()`? What makes them different? What do you do with `x` and `y`?

Comment: The sensors are analog values, so they have a different conversion thats why the different functions. De x and y are stored in an array and send to a database at the end of every loop

Comment: I don't know python very well so I will not try to give you a code snippet that might not work, but you simply need to do something similar to the below JS code,
`const activeSensors = ['sensor1', 'sensor4'];
activeSensors.forEach((sensor) => read (sensor));`

Comment: Are you expecting sensor active status to change while in loop?  And do you want your vars to remain *sticky* if not?  : in your code the last `y` value is kept if sensor2 drops out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop:

```py
funcs = [sensor1read, sensor2read, ...] # Store the functions in order
while True:
    actifs = [sensor1_actif, sensor2_actif, ...] # Store the variables in order
    sensor_readings = [None for _ in range(len(funcs))]
    for i, (func, actif) in enumerate(zip(funcs, actifs)): # Iterate through
        if actif: # Equivalent to if actif != 0
            sensor_readings[i] = func()
```

This stores the outputs in a list. `sensor_readings[0]` will be the output of the first function, `sensor_readings[1]` the output of the second function, etc. If the function did not get called it defaults to `None`.

Comment: OP is assigning the return of `sensor1read` etc to variables: so an equivalent solution needs to somehow do that too.  Maybe a list `sensor_readings`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps best to do this is with a control dictionary. Something like this:

```
def sensor1read():
    pass

def sensor2read():
    pass

CONTROL = {'sensor_1': {'active': True, 'func': sensor1read, 'val': None}, 'sensor_2': {'active': True, 'func': sensor2read, 'val': None}}

def read_sensors():
    for v in CONTROL.values():
        if v['active']:
            v['val'] = v['func']()
```

In this way you just set the 'active' value accordingly then this single function will update all values for all active sensors